# How to calculate features for forecasted time frame

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I have a question about how to calculate features for future time frames. Consider the below dataset and consider today is: `2019-11-11`. I have last 2 years of daily data and below is last 6 rows:

```
Date, Temperature, Sales

2019-11-06, 25.5, 500000

2019-11-07, 24.2, 550000

2019-11-08, 25.1, 560000

2019-11-09, 22.6, 510000

2019-11-10, 22.3, 520000

2019-11-11, 24.4, 535000
```

Now I have to predict Sales for 2019-11-12, 2019-11-13, 2019-11-14. In order to predict sales for those dates, I have to provide below test data to the machine learning trained model:

```
Date, Temperature

2019-11-12, temperatureX

2019-11-13, temperatureY

2019-11-14, temperatureZ
```

What will be values for temperatureX, temperatureY and temperatureZ since these values will be coming from future as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions.

I suggest you start with [Time-series Forecasting using Azure AutoML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-automated-ml#time-series-forecasting) or to dig deeper [Auto-train a time-series forecast model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-auto-train-forecast)

If you need an interpretable model you could train a Linear Model (LM) or an other regression model in R or Python. It might make sense to derive some features from the date such as month, day of month, season or so. This approach has the benefit that you can calculate the confidence interval.
As it is a multivariate time series, also have a look at Vector Auto Regression, see [A Multivariate Time Series Guide to Forecasting and Modeling (with Python codes)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/multivariate-time-series-guide-forecasting-modeling-python-codes/)

If you are just interested in predicting values, you can try a recurrent neural network or LSTM. See GitHub [Azure/DeepLearningForTimeSeriesForecasting](https://github.com/Azure/DeepLearningForTimeSeriesForecasting)

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer? You can't predict if you don't have the independent variables that explain your target at prediction time.

That being said, you can usually get a weather forecast for at least a week ahead of any date through a simple web search. So if you don't require a very large max horizon, you can use predicted weather forecasts for your temperature values (x, y, and z). Your retraining period would then become weekly, or however far out you're able to find existing weather forecasts.

Ref: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/what-to-give-as-predictors-to-predict-future-values